# mongoimport how to determine field names

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport, field-names

i have a .csv file that holds person datas.A line for a person like this.

```
"20781","IN","Ms.","Roy","","Serrano","2002-04-16 00:00:00","20781@adventure-works.com"
```

How can i give field names to mongoimport?

Field names -> id,type,firstname,middlename,lastname,modifieddate,e-mail.

Comment: The docs cover this: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption--fields

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do like Bellow

```
mongoimport -d test -c person -type csv --file person.csv --fields "id,type,firstname,middlename,lastname,modifieddate,e-mail"
```

this will import your file as in one document.

Comment: @nish71-yep,i found it on the internet also.Glads for help.